# how to compare values of 2 JSON files in java

Tags: java, json, comparison

I am working on JSON files to compare their data. I only want to check if value of 1 json is same as of 2nd json file.
both are having same key names and order.

JSON file data looks like :

> ```
> {   "ab_property": [
> {
>   "name": "abc",
>   "value": "1"
> },
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve your problem.Also you can direct match value using key instead of for loop.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Set;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class compareJsonFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/chandrakant/Desktop/json1.json"));
            Object obj1 = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/chandrakant/Desktop/json2.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) obj1;
            Set<String> s = jsonObject.keySet();
            for (String str : s) {
                System.out.println("key:" + str + " : value1:" + jsonObject.get(str) + ":value2:" + jsonObject1.get(str));
                //compare value of json1 with json2
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If something miss, please comment me.

Answer (score 2):

[JSONassert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) is a popular library to compare JSON objects. If the two files are identical (keys and values), it fits your use case.

An example using org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils to read the files:

```
String expected = IOUtils.toString(new File("/path/to/expected").toURI(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
String actual = IOUtils.toString(new File("/path/to/actual").toURI(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, actual, false);
```